# Regex Get String Subset

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

How can we get the substring based on fullstops using regex? We only wish to get the data after the full stop

```
Str = “i like cows. I also like camels”
// Regex Code here
Output : “I also like camels”
```

Comment: Do you have to use regex? `.split('.')` seems easier.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use regex for that. Use `split()` method.

```
splitted = Str.split('.')

# splitted[0] will be 'i like cows'
# splitted[1] will be 'I also like camels'
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `trim()` to remove leading whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach:

```
str1 = 'i like cows. I also like camels'
print(str1.split('.')[1:][0].strip())
```

output:

```
I also like camels
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this split

> String dataIWant = mydata.split(".")[1];

Result : I also like camels

Answer (score 1):

Using split('.') and selecting the last element is generally better but for **fun** this is a RegEx solution:

```
import re

Str = "i like .cows. I also like camels"
pattern = r"([^\.]*$)"

results = re.search(pattern, Str)
print(results.group(1).strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

This `(?:[.]\s([A-Z].+))` picks `"I also like camels"`